# Wemo Light Switch + Niko Dimmer Switch combined

Tags: lighting, switch

In order for my smart lights to be on permanently, I need the light switch circuit to be "permanently on", while the light switch instead controls my Hue lights. While I know this is accomplishable by replacing the light switch with a blank panel and using something like the link below (A wireless battery-less switch), I wanted to be able to control whether the circuit is on or not at the same time.

In other words, I want a wemo light switch without the actual physical switch, instead just a blank panel with wifi-controlled electricity. Any ideas?

Link to wireless dimmer switch: https://www.niko.eu/enus/article/120-91004

Answer (score 1):

### You still need a light switch where people expect one

The Building Codes require that you do have a functioning light switch in the usual locations.  That is not so much for you, they don't care if you can turn your lights on with your Google Glasses... They are a requirement for

- Guests who they don't want getting hurt in the dark
- EMTs so they can work 2-handed while saving your life, without holding a flashlight or delaying care so they can get you out to the ambulance where light is
- Firemen so they can quickly determine if the room is clear
- Police so they can quickly see that your son who got SWATed is holding a gaming mouse, not a gun

Obviously they are not mutually exclusive; with smart switches it does suffice for the wall switch to bepart of the smart-switch ecosystem send an "on command".  **It just has to work**.  The wall-switch "on" must easily bring it to a medium light level, what would be bad is if it was stuck at a previous very dim mood-lighting level that can only be changed from your phone.

If you are going to use your phone 99% of the time, a real risk is the batteries running down and you never knowing it.  So one option is to install a wired smart switch (controller) and re-task the physical wires to deliver always-on power to the switch.

### Don't use unlisted cheap Cheese junk

The item you linked is notable in its lack of a UL listing, or rather a listing from TUV, CSA, UL or some other competent testing lab which operates in Europe.  The only thing you see there is a CE mark, which stands for "Chinese Excrement" - seriously it's a *voluntary* mark which means the manufacturer *only claims* to comply with certain EU standards. In actual practice, far-east manufacturers stamp it on *absolutely everything*, so it might as well be bought at a street vendor in Bangkok.  The vendor states that proudly... so clearly they are not interested in paying the fee to have TUV or CSA test it, *since they know it'll fail*.

Well, buy from someone whose stuff actually is tested by an impartial third party.